# Vuelve a ingresar al sistema sino cierro sesión

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente al salir del sistema si cierro sesión funciona perfecto vuelve a la página de index.php y el usuario no puede volver a la pagina principal si no se loguea, ahora si no cierra sesión y le da volver atrás <-  en el navegador vuelve a la pagina de index.php, esto supone un fallo de seguridad porque un usuario podría volver atrás en vez de cerrar sesión y cualquier persona ajena puede entrar al sistema sin loguearse haciendo click **en -> adelante en el navegado**r ...adjunto código del archivo validar.php donde se envian los datos de la pagina de index.... tal vez si creara una variable de sesión igual a TRUE y luego verificarla en el header.php ...no se que puedo hacer...Desde ya gracias

// archivo validar.php

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$resultados = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from usuarios where user = '$username'");
if ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
    if ($password == $f['passadmin']) {
        $_SESSION['Id_usuario'] = $f['Id_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $f['user'];
        $_SESSION['rol'] = $f['rol'];
        $_SESSION['id_area'] = $f['id_area'];
        echo '<script>alert("Bienvenido administrador")</script>';
        echo '<script>location.href="admin.php"</script>';
    }
}

$resultados2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *  from usuarios where user = '$username'");
if ($f2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados2)) {
    if ($password == $f2['password']) {
        $_SESSION['Id_usuario'] = $f2['Id_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $f2['user'];
        $_SESSION['rol'] = $f2['rol'];
        $_SESSION['id_area'] = $f2['id_area'];

        echo '<script>location.href="../principal.php"</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("Contraseña incorrecta")</script>';
        echo '<script>location.href="../index.php"</script>';
    }
} else {

    echo '<script>alert("ESTE USUARIO NO EXISTE, POR FAVOR REGISTRESE PARA PODER INGRESAR")</script> ';

    echo "<script>location.href='../index.php'</script>";

}

?>
```

// adjunto codigo del header.php que es comun a todos los archivos del sistema

```
<header class="main-header hidden-print">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" style="max-height: 56px;">


    <ul class="pull-right" style="color:#EAF0ED  ;">

      <li><a style="color:#EAF0ED  "href="">Bienvenido: <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></strong> </a></li>
       <li><a style="color:#EAF0ED  ;"href="">Area: <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['id_area1']; ?></strong> </a></li>


      <li><a style="color:#EAF0ED  ;" href="desconectar.php"> Cerrar Sesión </a></li>

    </ul>



    <!-- Sidebar toggle button--><a class="sidebar-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="offcanvas"></a><h3 style="text-align: left">SISTEMA DE GESTION DE STOCKS   </h3>





    <!-- Navbar Right Menu-->




  </nav>


</header>
```

Comment: Al momento de cerrar sesión estas redireccionando a otra pagina al usuario ?

Comment: Si realmente te preocupa la seguridad, piensa en usar sentencias preparadas. Este código: `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *  from usuarios where user = '$username'");` **permite inyección sql**. Por otro lado no veo claro que significa terminar. ¿Que el usuario haga click en el enlace Cerrar Sesión? ¿Cómo se crea y registra el id de sesión?, ¿Se elimina (o marca como inválido) al terminar?, ¿Por qué no se valida si sigue siendo válido en cada solicitud de página?